# I've worked through the related SO questions, but I'm still having an issue. How do I package a program with images into onefile using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I googled for my problem and it lead me here: [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

So I added the accepted answer's code,

```
def resource_path(relative):
    return os.path.join(
        os.environ.get(
            "_MEIPASS2",
            os.path.abspath(".")
        ),
        relative
    )


# in development
>>> resource_path("app_icon.ico")
"/home/shish/src/my_app/app_icon.ico"

# in deployment
>>> resource_path("app_icon.ico")
"/tmp/_MEI34121/app_icon.ico"
```

But I still receive a `cannot locate imageName` error. With the exception that it lists the `_MEIPASS` folder.

Is there something I'm missing?

Let me know if more info is needed. As far as I'm concerned, `pyinstaller` is black magic, so I'm unsure what would be relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in this step too. Then I read pyinstaller.py file and have somehow managed to solve it successfully. After you modify the source file by adding the resource_path() method (as you have done already), you have to do the following steps:

1. Run:

   ```
   python utils\Makespec.py --onefile your_script_name.py
   ```
2. Next edit the your_script_name.spec file from your_script_name folder created from the first step. Add these lines( adjust for your image name)

   ```
   a.datas +=  [('relative path from pyinstaller folder','actual path to image file','DATA')]
   ```

   for example like this,

   ```
   a.datas += [('calvin.jpg','C:\\projects\\python\\calvin.jpg','DATA')]
   ```

   Note: I was not able to make it work, when I put my images in a subfolder so I kept them in the pyinstaller folder itself.
3. Then finally run this:

   ```
   python pyinstaller.py your_script_name\your_script_name.spec
   ```

   That is run pyinstaller with .spec file you edited in the second step.

Hope this helps clear all your doubts :)